# How to stop the Discord bot responds to other bots?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm new to programming a discord bot using discord.js (JavaScript). So, recently My bot got approved by discordbots.org. At the same day, I tested it. The result was other bot responds my command, but my bot wasn't. I check the logs in Heroku app, and there is an error. When I test the command into my server, it responds. So I think that there is a problem with my bot. When i checked my Bot's role in "Discord Bot Lists" server, I see that my bot gets a "Muted" Role. That mean there is a problem with my bot. When I check the mod logs channel, it shows that my bot is muted because my bot respond to other bot. How can I fix this so my bot get unmuted in that server? Sorry for my bad english and not providing the code.

Comment: It is hard to help if you don't provide any code.

Comment: "Sorry for my bad english and not providing the code" - we can't debug your bot's code without any code. I'm guessing that they muted you to stop your bot talking to other bots though because that could easily lead to spam - is this kind of behaviour definitely allowed on that server?

Comment: To avoid responding to other bots, I imagine that you'll have to check that the user your bot is responding to doesn't have the "Bot" role (or whatever your server calls that role). See if there's anything on https://anidiots.guide/understanding/roles about this to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I check the mod logs channel, it shows that my bot is muted because my bot respond to other bot.

Okay, so it seems you're muted because your bot responds to everyone, not just humans. Below is how to avoid responding to bots.

First, you need to get the Bot role ID (example of how to do it: [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/5bezg2/role_id/) or [here](https://anidiots.guide/understanding/roles#get-role-by-name-or-id)) or name.

Next, you need to ignore all messages from that role and only respond to messages if the sender doesn't have that role. For example, where BOT_ROLE is the bot's role or role id:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.member.roles.has(BOT_ROLE)) return; // do nothing
  // if not responding to a bot, do bot stuff
})
```

Alternatively, something simpler (you should have this from the tutorial [here](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html#basic-arguments) if you were following the official https://discordjs.guide tutorial):

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return; // do nothing
  // if not responding to a bot, do bot stuff
})
```

As for getting yourself unbanned, I've never had that problem so don't know. Maybe contact an admin for that server privately to see if what you've done is enough, or follow any official steps that the server sets out to get you unbanned.